# Why do regexes and string literals use different escape sequences?

Tags: regex, escaping, language-agnostic, string-literals

The handling of escape sequences varies across languages and between string literals and regular expressions. For example, in Python the `\s` escape sequence can be used in regular expressions but not in string literals, whereas in PHP the `\f` form feed escape sequence can be used in regular expressions but not in string literals.

In PHP, there is a dedicated page for PCRE escape sequences (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) but it does not have an official list of escape sequences that are exclusive to string literals.

As a beginner in programming, I am concerned that I may not have a full understanding of the background and context of this topic. Are these concerns valid? Is this an issue that others are aware of?

**Why do different programming languages handle escape sequences differently between regular expressions and string literals?**

[image]

Comment: if we are talking about regexp, for python - \s is for space character. \w is for alphabetic and number character, for php, as i know, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escape sequences found in string literals are there to stop the programing language from getting confused. For example, in many languages a string literal is denoted as characters between quotes, like so

```
my_string = 'x string'
```

But if your string contains a quote character then you need a way to tell the programming language that this should be interpreted as a literal character

```
my_string = 'x's string' # this will cause bugs
my_string = 'x\'s string' # lets the programing language know that the internal quote is literal and not the end of the string
```

I think that most programing languages have the same set of escape sequences for string literals.

Regexes are a different story, you can think of them as their own separate language that is written as a string literal. In a regex some characters like the period (.) have a special meaning and must be escaped to match their literal counterpart. Whereas other characters, when preceded by a backslash allow those characters to have special meaning.

For example

```
regex_string = 'A.C'  # match an A, followed by any character, followed by C
regex_string = 'A\.C' # match an A, followed by a period, followed by C
regex_string = 'AsC'  # match an A, followed by s, followed by C
regex_string = 'A\sC'  # match an A, followed by a space character, followed by C
```

Because regexes are their own mini-language it doesn't make sense that all of the escape sequences in regexes are available to normal string literals.

Comment: to clarify, 
regexes are their "own" language and therefore something like `\.abc` will match a literal period followed by the letters abc in some given string.
The problem is, now give me some rope here, is that since regexes are there "own independent language" oftentimes we have to represent/code this "other language" in the string of some language (php/python) which just HAPPENS to have the same delimiters as regex. So the actual "Package" we need to hand to the regex compiler is `\.abc` but what we end up coding is something more akin to `\\.abc`. Yes?

Comment: Failure to standardize would also be a result of this same distinction? That regexes are their own language? Yes?

Comment: your correct that in some languages that you have to do a double escape, in others you do not; this is a problem with standardizing how strings are parsed by each language.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are best thought of as a language in themselves, which have their own syntax. Some programming languages offer a literal syntax specifically for describing a regex, but usually a regex will be compiled from an existing string. If you create that string from literal syntax, that uses a different set of escape sequences because **it is a different kind of thing, created with a different syntax, for a different context, in a different language**. That's the simple and direct answer to the question.

There are different needs and requirements. Regexes have to be able to describe things that aren't a single, specific sequence of text. String literals obviously don't have that problem, but they do need a way to, say, include quotation marks in the text. That usually isn't a problem for regex syntax, because the content of the string is already determined by that point. (Some languages have a "regex literal" syntax, typically enclosing the regex in forward slashes. In these languages, forward slashes that are supposed to be part of the regex need to be escaped.)

> Although I understand the obvious (\s represents multiple characters and would introduce ambiguity)

Ambiguity isn't actually a concern for most languages that support regex. It often happens that the string literal syntax and the regex syntax use the same sequence to mean different things. For example: `\b` represents a word boundary in regex syntax, but many languages' string literal syntax also uses it to represent a backspace character, Unicode code point 8. (Unless you meant that `\s` to mean "any whitespace character" doesn't make sense in the string literal context but only in the regex context - then yes, of course.)

But keep in mind - if the regex is being compiled from a string literal, then first the string literal is interpreted to figure out what the string *actually contains*, and then that string is used to create the regex. These are *separate steps that can and do apply separate rules*, so there is no conflict.

This sometimes means that code has to use a double escaping mechanism: first for the string literal, and then for the regex syntax. If you want a regex that matches a literal backslash, you might end up typing *four* backslashes in a string literal - since that code will create a string that *actually contains* only two backslashes, which in turn is what the regex syntax requires. (Some languages offer some kind of "raw" string literal facility to work around this.)